# "encore jamais" vs "jamais" ?

Tags: sens, choix-de-mot, indications-de-temps, adverbes

I would have translated "I have never visited France" as *Je n'ai jamais visité la France*, but apparently you could just as easily say *Je n'ai encore jamais visité la France.*

But what's the difference? Do the two sentences mean the same thing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*encore* can be translated in this context as *yet*, implying that you intend to go one day.

I think a French speaker would rather say:
*Je ne suis jamais allé en France* → I've never been to France
*Je ne suis encore jamais allé en France* → I've never been to France yet

Comment: (Do you pronounce the liaison on *jamais allé* ? Guessing no.)

Comment: Yes. And it will sound like a Z.

Comment: In spoken french, the liaison may be ommited, you may hear "J'sui encore jamai allé en France"

Comment: Wouldn't a more idiomatic order of words be *jamais encore* instead of *encore jamais*?

Comment: No "je ne suis jamais encore alle en France" would sound weird. If anyone would say that (we sometimes speak fast), everybody would understand though.